# How to go about incorporating asp.net mvc with a site template or theme

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, themes

I want to use a bought theme for a site that I am going to build.
For example:

http://themeforest.net/item/ciaohost-responsive-hosting-html-template/full_screen_preview/5062293

Now i want to use the ASP.net mvc 4 model to develop my site.

How would i go about incorporating the theme with the MVC ?